# sqlite3 is giving me (type,) instead of "type"

Tags: python, sqlite

My Sqlite3 database is giving me (type,) instead of "type" when I'm trying to print something in the database (note that the "type" thing is from the database)

here's my code :

```
    c.execute("SELECT type FROM accounts")
    acctype = c.fetchall()
    print(acctype[0])
```

the output is (type,)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

acctype is a list of tuples so:

```py
print(acctype[0][0])
```